# Do the latest DotCMIS still support CMIS 1.0 repositories?

Tags: cmis, dotcmis

I have always thought that DotCMIS supports both CMIS 1.0 and CMIS 1.1 repositories.

But now I am being [told otherwise](http://community.exoplatform.com/portal/intranet/forum/topic/topicb760f4bc0a20d9900f9ccf5c8e9fc72e), that DotCMIS (by extension: CmisSync) does not support CMIS 1.0.

How is it actually?
Do recent versions of DotCMIS still support CMIS 1.0 repositories?

Comment: I think that `PortCMIS` might be your best bet, that is a .net portable class library with CMIS 1.1 support, should be at Apache Chemistry shortly all being well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotCMIS only supports CMIS 1.0 repositories. It might work with CMIS 1.1 repositories, but that's not a supported scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Current dotCMIS versions support only CMIS 1.0

If you are interested in using dotCMIS with CMIS 1.1 you should follow the instructions on this link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-742
Its just a "partial patch" but better than nothing.

Hope it might help someone...

Comment: Thanks! Actually this patch was written by me ;-)

Comment: I'm using it and I'm very satisfied with it!
Great work!